# Do metals with different electrical conductivities have different succeptibilities to induction?

Tags: inductance, metal

If you have an inductive levitation coil and you gradually increase the strength of the AC current to the coils, could you fraction off metal powders by levitating each of them separately due to their differing electrical conductivities and thus different susceptibilities to electromagnetic induction?

I.e. will certain elements levitate before the others at differing induction levitation coil strengths due to their differing electrical conductivities and thus succeptibilities to induction?

Comment: I don't have an authoritative answer just a gut feeling. Particles will be too small to have much induction at all unless the frequency is very high. That is my first observation. As long as the particles are touching each other there may be bulk induction but then if they separate they will fall back down the gravity well. If you need to separate aluminum and copper it might be easier to use some type of density based separation scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the different conductivities will mean different currents flow in the materials, it's not going to help you separate an aluminimium powder from a copper powder. Unfortunately the force the grains will experience in an AC field will be strongly affected by the grain size. You'll end up fractionating the mixed power into grain size rather than element.

Comment: And density will be involved.